# Numpy array variable avoid bad calculations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm setting a numpy array with a power-law equation. The problem is that part of my domain tries to do numpy.power(x, n) when x is negative and n is not an integer. In this part of the domain I want the value to be 0.0. Below is a code that has the correct behavior, but is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

```
# note mesh.x is a numpy array of length nx
myValues = npy.zeros((nx))
para = [5.8780046, 0.714285714, 2.819250868] 
for j in range(nx):
    if mesh.x[j] > para[1]:
        myValues[j] = para[0]*npy.power(mesh.x[j]-para[1],para[2])

    else:
        myValues[j] = 0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is "numpythonic" a word?  It should be a word.  The following is really neither pythonic nor unpythonic, but it is much more efficient than using a `for` loop, and close(r) to the way [Travis](https://www.continuum.io/people/travis-oliphant) would probably do it:

```
import numpy
mesh_x = numpy.array([0.5,1.0,1.5])
myValues = numpy.zeros_like( mesh_x )
para = [5.8780046, 0.714285714, 2.819250868] 
mask = mesh_x > para[1]
myValues[mask] = para[0] * numpy.power(mesh_x[mask] - para[1], para[2])
print(myValues)
```

For very large problems you would probably want to avoid creating temporary arrays:

```
mask = mesh.x > para[1]
myValues[mask] = mesh.x[mask]
myValues[mask] -= para[1]
myValues[mask] **= para[2]
myValues[mask] *= para[0]
```

Comment: The first clips throws an exception.  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\choutman\Documents\confocal beads\Modelling\Carl_1D_coupled_time.py", line 85, in <module>
    myValues[mask] = para[0] * npy.power(mesh.x[mask] - para[1], para[2]) {{clip}}File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\variables\unaryOperatorVariable.py", line 67, in _calcValue_
    return self.op(self.var[0].value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\variables\variable.py", line 1572, in <lambda>
    return self._UnaryOperatorVariable(lambda a: a[index],
IndexError: unsupported iterator index

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. I have edited my answer to include a complete example that runs for me.  You might get problems if your `mesh.x` is not a standard `numpy.array`, but rather a `matrix` or other derived class - could this be the case?  If so, maybe say `mask=(numpy.asarray(mesh.x)>para[1])` to be safe.

Comment: Yes, exactly. mesh.x is a class derived from FiPy. When I cast it as a numpy array as you suggest, it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach with [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to choose values between the power calculations and `0` -

```
import numpy as np
np.where(mesh.x>para[1],para[0]*np.power(mesh.x-para[1],para[2]),0)
```

**Explanation :**

1. `np.where(mask,A,B)` chooses elements from A or B depending on `mask` elements. So, in our case it is `mesh.x>para[1]` when doing a vectorized comparison for all `mesh.x` elements in one go.
2. `para[0]*np.power(mesh.x-para[1],para[2])` gives us the elements that are to be chosen in case a mask element is `True`. Else, we choose `0`, which is the third argument to `np.where`.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about this usage of `numpy.where` that I wasn't aware of, but back to 0 for the fact that the subtraction, exponentiation and multiplication happen for **all** elements of `mesh.x` which are then selected post-hoc.  Would this not make the result a complex array, because of the cases that violate the condition?

Comment: uhh, apparently not, if `mesh.x` isn't complex to begin with: instead it returns `nan` in the bad locations.  Again I learn something.  *But* you *do* get `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`

Comment: @jez I think those *bad* locations would be covered up by the else part of `0` filling, right?

Comment: yes, they are covered up but the calculation still happens (wasting CPU time and issuing the warning) for the bad values. That's what I mean by "selected post-hoc".

Comment: I first tried the np.where and got this: C:\Users\choutman\Documents\confocal beads\Modelling\Carl_1D_coupled_time.py:84: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  npy.where(mesh.x>para[1],para[0]*npy.power(mesh.x-para[1],para[2]),0)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fipy\variables\binaryOperatorVariable.py:81: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
  return self.op(self.var[0].value, val1)

Comment: @CarlHoutman As discussed in the comments earlier, those are for the *bad* places that are set later on by `zeros`, when `np.where` chooses based on the mask.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, the code still works numerically, but when I pass the code on to my cooperator it seemed like bad form to have it throwing a warning.

Answer (score 0):

More of an explanation of the answers given by @jez and  @Divakar with simple examples than an answer itself.  They both rely on some form of [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays).

```
>>> 
>>> a
array([[-4.5, -3.5, -2.5],
       [-1.5, -0.5,  0.5],
       [ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5]])
>>> n = 2.2
>>> a ** n
array([[         nan,          nan,          nan],
       [         nan,          nan,   0.21763764],
       [  2.44006149,   7.50702771,  15.73800567]])
```

`np.where` is made for this it selects one of two values based on a boolean array.

```
>>> np.where(np.isnan(a**n), 0, a**n)
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.21763764],
       [  2.44006149,   7.50702771,  15.73800567]])
>>> 
>>> b = np.where(a < 0, 0, a)
>>> b
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0.5],
       [ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5]])
>>> b **n
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.21763764],
       [  2.44006149,   7.50702771,  15.73800567]])
```

Use of boolean indexing on the *left-hand-side* and the *right-hand-side*.  This is similar to `np.where`

```
>>> 
>>> a[a >= 0] = a[a >= 0] ** n
>>> a
array([[ -4.5       ,  -3.5       ,  -2.5       ],
       [ -1.5       ,  -0.5       ,   0.21763764],
       [  2.44006149,   7.50702771,  15.73800567]])
>>> a[a < 0] = 0
>>> a
array([[  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,   0.21763764],
       [  2.44006149,   7.50702771,  15.73800567]])
>>>
```